# Adding a image to bitbucket source

Tags: html, bitbucket

How do you add a image to a bitbucket html website?

I have tried doing this:

```
<img src="cool.jpg" alt="test" width="500" height="600">
```

It did not work. I also imported the image to downloads and it still did not work